# Can We call Web API in Windows Application programming?

Tags: windows, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am new to Windows phone programming, I gone through google and search for the example , but not getting actual solution from it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please mention why r u mark negative...

Comment: WebAPI is not just for web application. Any application type if it can process HTTP request, HTTP response can invoke it. About the downvoting, stackoverflow is about programming and most of the time, questions asking about examples/simple explanations / suggestions are not encouraged and usually gets down voting. This community expects us to do some research on our own.

Comment: i accept answer from you.how to call api in windows phone application.bcz i'm new in windows phone development.